# ¿Como hacer para que el contructor de una clase derivada de un singleton templatizado sea private? C#

Tags: c#, singleton

Estoy haciendo un singleton templatizado. El problema es que el consumirlo me pide que el constructor de la clase derivada sea público. ¿hay alguna forma de restringir el acceso al constructor de la clase derivada?

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static T _instance;

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new T();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}


public class Derivada : Singleton<Derivada>
{

}
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si no tenes un constructor publico, como se supone que arme la clase?

Comment: Para eso precisamente es el singleton... para tener una sola instancia... por eso precisamente nadie puede usar el constructor... tiene que ser privado por obligación si no se podrian crear mas de una instancia

Comment: lee por aca... https://stackoverflow.com/q/16865413/73749.. como suponia, nadie recomienda algo asi...

Comment: Si, tiene muy mala fama... pero todo depende de como lo uses... y realmente puede llegar a ser muy útil.... Gracias por el enlace!!

Comment: nunca hice un singleton Generico, pero no le veo el sentido a lo que haces, ya que se llama a si mismo, tambien le colocas la restriccion del new lo que te obligaria a crear un objeto mediante constructor y lo pondrias privado. Me esta haciendo volar la cabeza.

Comment: pero al derivarlo, no deja de ser singleton? o sea... la clase hija, puede ser instanciada mil veces, porque la clase padre es la que es single...

Comment: la finalidad de ese patrón es tener una única instancia de la clase... no hace nada mas que eso... (El constructor es privado pero la propia clase si lo puede usar dentro de sus metodos)

Comment: Entiendo el patron perfectamente... no entiendo porque derivarlo a otra clase...

Comment: Si gbianchi, asi es... por eso quiero restringir el aceso al constructor... voy a probar haciendo abstracto como el link que me has pasado a ver si asi funciona

Comment: (no entiendo porque derivarlo a otra clase) --> simple comodidad... hay que repetir codigo lo menos posible!! :-)

Comment: lo de ponerlo "abstract" no funcionó... parece que el lenguage ya no permite templatizar clases abstractas...

Comment: mira aca: https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton tu singleton no es thread safe...

Comment: ¿Pero eso es para programación concurrente?¿O también aplica cuando hay un solo hilo?

Comment: De todas formas muchas gracias!!... me lo quedo!! mas vale prevenir que curar!! por si las mocas!!

Comment: para ahorra codigo, me parece que podrias usar Reflection para crear tu clase, pero en teoria tiene un costo mayor de CPU.

Comment: Ok, le doy un vistazo a eso... no se mucho sobre la reflexion... lo poco que he visto me dió ha entender que era para testear clases... me informare mejor... Gracias!!

Comment: tiene mucho mas potencial

Comment: Ok, voy a mirarlo!! Gracias Ramiro!!